# Does aloe vera fade acne scars?

Tags: dermatology, topical-cream-gel, acne, scar-tissue-scars, aloe-vera

Can aloe vera gel make scars from acne fade? If so, how is it used for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is used as a gel.

[WebMd.com](http://www.m.webmd.com/vitamins/ai/ingredientmono-607/aloe)

> Aloe seems to be able to speed wound healing by improving blood
>   circulation through the area and preventing cell death around a wound.
>
> It also appears that aloe gel has properties that are harmful to
>   certain types of bacteria and fungi.

Aloe - [ncbi.nlh.nih.gov](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4025519/):

- anti-inflammatory
- skin soothing

Aloe Vera has been shown effective on scars [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4257949/).

Answer (score -4):

It can. It depends on your skin type. Anatomically, everyone is different. I've seen it work quite well and not so well other times. 
For the most part it does work. It's compound and gentle nature and nurture of your dermis is what allows it to heal the outer layer of your skin.
Vitamin E is what most people refer to in scar healing. Cocoa butter is another over the counter remedy for this as well.

Comment: how long it takes for average scars to heal?i have oily skin.i can see it is doing wonderful job on my acne but iam worried about the scars caused by it.and is it enough if i wash it after 15 minutes because this is winter and iam afraid that it may dry my skin too much.

Comment: Welcome to Health SE! This post has the makings of a good answer, but here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283) Thanks :)